# How to print the first line of first column and second column as a single column with awk?

Tags: awk

I am trying to print the first line of first column and second column into single column with awk. I am using the following awk one-liner

`awk 'NR==1{printf $1 OFS; next}{print $2}' infile > new_file`

```
Input:
A123 154.1
A123 158.1
A123 159.4

Expected Output:
A123
154.1
158.1
159.4
```

But the resulted output from the one-liner is as follows

```
A123 154.1
158.1
159.4
```

I would like to what mistake causes the change in output. I included '\n' in the code but not helping.

Thank you in advance

Comment: can your input contain different value for first column? if not, does `awk 'NR==1{print $1} {print $2}' infile` solve your problem?

Comment: Always use a format string with `printf` -> `printf "%s%s", $1, ORS` -- if $1 is `%s` you'll get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** I would go with following approach so that we can handle multiple ids too, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '{a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1] ORS:"")$2} END{for(i in a){print i ORS a[i]}}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Considering if your Input_file's 1st field is sorted then try following.

```
awk 'prev!=$1{print $1 ORS $2;prev=$1;next} {print $2}' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** In case your Input_file is not sorted with 1st column then `sort` it and run the `awk` code.

```
sort -k1 Input_file | awk 'prev!=$1{print $1 ORS $2;prev=$1;next} {print $2}'
```

Comment: Thank U.. I have gone through 1st solution and it worked fine. I don't want to sort the input and the data was not in sorted format. So I tried 1st solution. Thank U Ravinder.

Answer (score 3):

If this doesn't work, please add a better input/output sample.

```sh
$ awk 'NR==1{print $1} {print $2}' infile
A123
154.1
158.1
159.4
```

Also, output of `awk` command shown in the question doesn't match given sample. It should be this:

```sh
$ awk 'NR==1{printf $1 OFS; next}{print $2}' infile
A123 158.1
159.4
```

Unlike `print` function, `printf` doesn't add automatically add the value of `ORS`. And because of `next`, `$2` of first line isn't printed.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you. It is simple. Actually, I tried this but with && and which gave me different output. I missed the simple logic. Actually I tried just with print and it was not gave the required output. I agree with your solution.